# Pritunl server log location

Tags: logging, pritunl

Installed pritunl server on Amazon linux Ec2 instance.Able to see information about user connections and user-id on pritunl web UI server output section.

[image]

I want to store these logs to debug if any issue occurs in future. But pritunl documentation shows log location as /var/log/pritunl.log , this location has don't has required information.

Can anyone help with the location in Ec2.